# Blackberry batch import for zip file for submission with app world gives invalid binary error

Tags: macos, blackberry, import

I've developed a Blackberry app using Eclipse running on an Apple Mac. Developing in this way meant I had to test directly on devices as there is no simulator I can find for a Mac. Now the app is packaged and ready for upload, I've used the batch import option through my vendor account but I keep getting an Invalid Binary error and it is referring to files DS_Store with lots of digits attached. Anyone come across this or know what these files are?  There is nothing in my zip archive other than my app cod files and a devices.txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `DS_Store` folders are created automatically on Apple Macs and are hidden. So, when I created my release folder with my bundle of cod files and `devices.txt` file, the `DS_Store` folders were being added automatically. To remove them, open a terminal window (through Utilities) and type in the following command:

```
find . -name '*.DS_Store' -type f -delete
```

This will recursively remove the hidden `DS_Store` folders from all the sub folders. I did this from my top level folder and then re-created my zip archive file to upload to my Blackberry vendor account. It was successful!

Answer (score 1):

Please following this step to .zip file for a release:
[Contents of a .zip file for a release](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25819/Options_for_a_zip_file_for_a_release_664581_11.jsp)

Comment: Thanks - I followed this guidance when I first built my release bundle :-)